# Standard deviation for Gaussian distribution in Matlab

Tags: statistics, matlab

I have a number of test data (400 samples) that are distributed according to the Gaussian distribution, N(0,sigma). Is there a simple way of calculating the sample standard deviation sigma for these in Matlab? I have used the std function but I'm not sure whether it's correct, since I cannot see any assumptions on distribution in the matlab help except that it's identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `std` [command](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/std.html) in Matlab does not assume uniformly distributed samples. The command `std(x)` is simply calculating the quantity
$$
\hat{\sigma}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})^2}
$$
with $\bar{x}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i$ for a vector `x` of length $n$. You can easily calculate this quantity by hand and compare with the `std` command.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was exactly what I was hoping for. I apparently misread the help section a bit, which I discovered now.